# Производительность 10Gbe на TCP и UDP

Tags: linux, сеть, tcp, udp, cisco

Есть два сервера подключенных через 10Gbe свитч Сisco sg350xg-24t
Карты Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)
Наблюдаю очень низкую производительность на UDP, высокая латентность, большие потери.
Но на TCP все отлично.
Не могу найти объяснение этому. Может кто нить подсказать, почему так ? Ниже приведены результаты тестов:
Тест на UDP: `iperf -c 10.10.10.3 -i 1 -b 10G -u -e`

```
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total  Latency avg/min/max/stdev PPS
[  4] local 10.10.10.3 port 5001 connected with 10.10.10.4 port 48233
[  4] 0.00-1.00 sec   577 MBytes  4.84 Gbits/sec   0.004 ms 250113/662049 (38%)  7.954/ 7.917/ 8.732/ 0.023 ms 411924 pps
[  4] 1.00-2.00 sec   570 MBytes  4.78 Gbits/sec   0.001 ms 245694/651975 (38%)  7.955/ 7.914/ 8.038/ 0.016 ms 406292 pps
[  4] 2.00-3.00 sec   565 MBytes  4.74 Gbits/sec   0.007 ms 277045/679862 (41%)  7.954/ 7.912/ 8.046/ 0.015 ms 402813 pps
[  4] 3.00-4.00 sec   570 MBytes  4.78 Gbits/sec   0.003 ms 250685/657553 (38%)  7.950/ 7.909/ 8.033/ 0.016 ms 406861 pps
[  4] 4.00-5.00 sec   573 MBytes  4.80 Gbits/sec   0.003 ms 263988/672481 (39%)  7.946/ 7.907/ 8.030/ 0.016 ms 408500 pps
[  4] 5.00-6.00 sec   575 MBytes  4.82 Gbits/sec   0.002 ms 255955/665858 (38%)  7.945/ 7.905/ 8.029/ 0.015 ms 409897 pps
[  4] 6.00-7.00 sec   596 MBytes  5.00 Gbits/sec   0.004 ms 241399/666408 (36%)  7.940/ 7.902/ 8.039/ 0.016 ms 424992 pps
[  4] 7.00-8.00 sec   577 MBytes  4.84 Gbits/sec   0.004 ms 250347/662174 (38%)  7.940/ 7.900/ 8.027/ 0.016 ms 411834 pps
[  4] 8.00-9.00 sec   567 MBytes  4.76 Gbits/sec   0.001 ms 263960/668624 (39%)  7.939/ 7.898/ 8.018/ 0.016 ms 404684 pps
[  4] 0.00-10.00 sec  5.60 GBytes  4.81 Gbits/sec   0.002 ms 2571225/6662198 (39%)  7.946/ 7.896/ 8.732/ 0.018 ms 409124 pps
```

Тест на TCP: `iperf -c 10.10.10.3 -i 1 -b 10G -e`

```
[  4] local 10.10.10.3 port 5001 connected with 10.10.10.4 port 44798
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Reads   Dist(bin=16.0K)
[  4] 0.00-1.00 sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec  15395    378:6617:437:145:67:6:8:7737
[  4] 1.00-2.00 sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec  15318    597:6024:615:192:138:1:3:7748
[  4] 2.00-3.00 sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec  15290    653:5824:707:206:151:5:7:7737
[  4] 3.00-4.00 sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec  15349    503:6182:613:185:115:10:19:7722
[  4] 4.00-5.00 sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec  15322    635:5910:711:204:108:3:2:7749
[  4] 5.00-6.00 sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec  15287    695:5687:773:249:132:6:7:7738
[  4] 6.00-7.00 sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec  15350    555:6168:611:172:92:2:1:7749
[  4] 7.00-8.00 sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec  15338    620:5995:644:207:122:3:9:7738
[  4] 8.00-9.00 sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec  15316    532:6068:627:220:118:1:0:7750
[  4] 9.00-10.00 sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec  15458    179:7168:268:51:41:0:0:7751
[  4] 0.00-10.01 sec  11.5 GBytes  9.89 Gbits/sec  153457    5347:61660:6007:1831:1084:37:56:77435
```

Comment: Для начала я бы выяснил, является ли причиной свитч или нет, исключив его из канала (ваши десятки могут быть соединены напрямик?)
И попробуйте UDP-тест с заданием ширины канала 80-85% от номинала.

Answer (score 0):

Частично, я нашел в чем проблема.
Генерируется большое количество пакетов между двумя адресами (примерно 600K в секунду). Они попадают в одну очередь на обработку, а значит обрабатываются одним ядром. Ядро не справляется, появляются потери. Сетевых проблем тут нет.
Я не понял, почему tcp не генерирует такую нагрузку. Сейчас это не важно.